# Read data from S3 for Mobile applications- Allow only particular domain

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, amazon-s3, cross-domain

S3 bucket allows to read the data for the application by setting AllowedOrigins as *. Instead of allowing every origin, how can we restrict the access in s3 bucket for the mobile application?

Comment: You can create a CorsRule with one or more "AllowedOrigins" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-cors-corsrule.html#cfn-s3-bucket-cors-corsrule-allowedorigins
There is an example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#aws-properties-s3-bucket--examples  that you can use as template. Hope this helps.

Comment: @suprasad 
       Thanks for sharing the information. The aforementioned solution helps on how to add more than one origin but my concern is how to provide the access only for the requests that come from the mobile application.
In general, we can restrict the web appl access using the urls. For instance,AllowedOrigins: "https://myexample.com".
 But in mobile application, how can I prevent other domains?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566453/amazon-bucket-policy-for-only-mobile-app-access this has a similar scenario Check it out.

Comment: Thanks @suprasad , this is really helpful