# Unable to use the signedUrl provided by Flutter Amplify to Access S3 Bucket Images

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, flutter-aws-amplify

Migrating an AWS Service from React-Native Application to New Flutter Application.

I have come into trouble when it comes to getting the signed url to access images.
I get the following error when trying to access them using the given url:

Handshake error in client (OS Error:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: application verification failure(handshake.cc:393)

when inspecting the URL outputs between flutter and react-native's sdk functions, I did notice that the host construction was reversed

s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{bucketname}       In react native
{bucketname}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/      In Flutter

and tried a string operation to match these up as one quick way to solve this issue, resulting in a 403 error.

I don't have credentials to access the server, only all the setup details from the react-native application. So if some extra setup is needed in AWS to support the flutter's output, please let me know so I can communicate this directly to someone with credentials.

Thanks

Comment: To access S3 resources, Amazon STS needs to be used. Please have a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566453/amazon-bucket-policy-for-only-mobile-app-access/45568731#45568731

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following snippet from an amplify-flutter issue helped.

"Is your bucket with a domain name for example 'dev.aaa.com'?.
bucket name with a domain name resolves bucket endpoint as dev.aaa.com.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com which may cause Dart HTTP client to interpret the SSL certificate.
Can you try to use a different bucket name".
Complete discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/3105)

Comment: refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html